# Why mbstring extension is missing?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Im trying to increase max execution time of PHP script with line

`ini_set('max_execution_time', 90000);`

In "php.ini" file, but after I restart server I got error in PHPMyAdmin "mbstring extension is missing". If I comment line with "ini_set" PHPMyAdmin works fine.

So, why mbstring extension stop working?

Comment: Can you install mbstring with command line tool? Like sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php.ini` is a **configuration** file, not a **script**, so you cannot run code from it. When you attempt to fill it with PHP source code you break the file so PHP starts with its compiled-in defaults, which do not include mbstring.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time = 30
```